# Sending data from custom UITableViewCell to detail ViewController - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-cell, detailview

I'm relatively new to programming and this is my first attempt at developing an iOS without following a tutorial, so please bear with me.

I have a custom table view called 'CupboardViewController' that returns four string labels based on a custom UITableViewCell class called 'ItemTableViewCell'. I want to be able to show those four labels in a separate view controller called 'detailViewController' when a user clicks on a table item.

This is the code I have but it's crashing with no obvious error message when the segue is called. Please help!

CupboardViewController

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue,
    sender: AnyObject!) {
        // sender is the tapped `UITableViewCell`
        let cell = sender as! ItemTableViewCell
        let indexPath = self.tblItems.indexPathForCell(cell)

        // load the selected model
        let titleToPass = itemMgr.items[indexPath!.row].name

        let detail = segue.destinationViewController as! detailViewController
        // set the model to be viewed
        detail.titleToPass = titleToPass
}
```

}

detailViewController

```
@IBOutlet weak var titleDetailLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var qtyDetailLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var dateDetailLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var descriptionDetailLabel: UILabel!

var titleToPass: String!
var qtyToPass: String!
var descriptionToPass: String!
var dateToPass: String!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    titleDetailLabel.text = titleToPass
    qtyDetailLabel.text = qtyToPass
    dateDetailLabel.text = dateToPass
    descriptionDetailLabel.text = descriptionToPass
}

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
```

ItemTableViewCell

```
@IBOutlet weak var itemTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var itemSubtitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var itemSubDetail: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var dateDetail: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {


    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
```

Comment: As a generally rule, try to avoid forced unwrap of Optionals (eg. as!), unless you are absolutely sure they won't be nil. Instead you should use "if let" or "guard". That way you can cater for them being nil, which is probably what's happening. What is the exact error you're getting, and on what line?

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely best to avoid the force unwrap `!` as much as possible, so I'd definitely recommend using `guard let` or `if let` in most cases.  In addition to saving you from crashes, they also offer some great ways to see exactly where your code is failing that are otherwise tougher to track down.

For example, you have this line, which returns an optional NSIndexPath

```
let indexPath = self.tblItems.indexPathForCell(cell)
```

Rather than force unwrapping this optional, you can modify the line slightly to make it handle nil, and also add a print to tell you that this line failed, like this:

```
guard let indexPath = self.tblItems.indexPathForCell(cell) else {
    print("No index path returned.")
    return
}
```

If the value is not nil you can operate with the `indexPath` constant like you normally would.  You'll probably want to continue this approach with most of these optionals, unless you're 100% sure they won't be nil in any situation.

As for your particular crash, you can correct me if I'm wrong, but I suspect it's because you have those four variables on your detailViewController that are being accessed in viewDidLoad, but you're only setting one of them in the segue.  This means that in viewDidLoad you will be trying to access those (and they have the `!` too), and since it won't find anything it'll crash immediately.  See if fixing that, and getting rid of some of the `!`s helps.